# Grails app can't be opened in Google browser

Tags: grails, android-browser

we have a strange problem.

Our Grails App works fine, and can be opened in various browsers, despite the Built in Google Browser at Android. If I try to open the app I always get an 401 Error. No Exception is thrown.

Everything works fine in other browsers (like Chrome or Opera).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by any chance redirected to login/authAjax?
In that case you are probably experiencing http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-197
This happens because the browser for some reason sends X-Requested-With (with value "com.android.browser") even if it's not an ajax request.

Comment: Yes this was the problem, now we redirect the ajax call direct to the normal auth page